# Point cloud using depth at each pixel location

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds, stereo-3d

Is there any way to get Point cloud from the depth data at each pixel. I have zed stereo camera which give the depth information at each pixel location but i want x and y too.
Zed camera directly give Point cloud also but it is Unorganized and i want the organized one.

Comment: What do you mean by "each pixel location"? Do you have the resolution of the Zed camera (i.e. width and height)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Dexter, i have the resolution means the image rows and columns and at each pixel location z coordinate (depth) is known.

Actually now i have got the answer how to find X and Y coordinates.
X = x1 * Z / f

Y = y1 * Z / f 
where x1 and y1 are columns and rows.
For more you can look at this link.

http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~iocchi/stereo/triang.html